# ASP.NET MVC and HTML TypeScript Projects Difference

Tags: typescript

I have a problem that I suppose comes from my ASP.NET MVC project using Type Script. For testing I have created a project using the HTML TypeScript template. I could perfectly create two modules and use one of them in the other like this:

```
import authModule = module("Authenticate");
import testModule = module("TestModule");

export module SiteMaster {
  authModule.Authenticate.run();
  testModule.TestModule.run();
}
```

It is generating correctly the JavaScript like this:

```
define(["require", "exports", "Authenticate", "TestModule"], function(require, exports, __authModule__, __testModule__) {
  var authModule = __authModule__;
  var testModule = __testModule__;

  (function (SiteMaster) {
    authModule.Authenticate.run();
    testModule.TestModule.run();
  })(exports.SiteMaster || (exports.SiteMaster = {}));
})
```

Then I have copied to my ASP.NET MVC 4.5 the compiler command from my Typescript project.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot; --module amd @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
```

It is compiling correctly. Apparently is compiling correctly.

But there is a problem: when I create the same modules in my ASP.NET MVC application I receive the compilation errors in the import line:

```
The name '"Authenticate"' does not exist in the current scope
A module cannot be aliased to a non-module
```

Ths same for TestModule.

I have included a reference below to the module and the error remains, and look in the Typescript template the reference was not necessary.

```
/// <reference path='Authenticate.ts'/>
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem. As I suspected it was in the compiler command. I fact I was not using the compiler command generated the TypeScript template.

I was using, in my ASP.NET MVC project this command:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot; --module amd -target ES5 @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
```

This compiler command here is working:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot; --module amd @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
```

Can someone explain me what is the meaning of the target parameter.

Comment: Typescript supports targetting ECMAScript 5 language features. If you don't specify ES5 as target it will assume the default ECMAScript Version 3.

Comment: But when I use the ECMAScript 5 I cannot compile the import. What should I do to compile the import command and use ECMAScript 5 ?

Comment: I'm pretty much convinced that this is not an ECMAScript 5 problem. However, to debug this I would need all code in order to compile it myself. Can you create a gist?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET 4.5, I would personally recommend using bundles, rather than AMD module loading - unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Remove `--module amd` from the Exec config and convert your `import` statements into `/// <reference path=` statements and set up your bundle in bundle_config.

If you are targeting ES5, you use:

```
--target ES5
```

But you should only need to do this if you are using getters and setters, which is the only TypeScript language feature that cannot work on ECMAScript 3.